# jquery убрать стрелку "наверх"

Tags: html, jquery, css

При разрешении меньше чем 992px необходимо убрать стрелочку наверх. Пытался сделать через медиа запрос - не выходит. На jquery тоже не получается. Прошу помо

```
var $backToTop = $(".back-to-top");
$backToTop.hide();
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
$backToTop.fadeIn();
} else {
$backToTop.fadeOut();
}
});




$backToTop.on('click', function(e) {
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 992 ){
    $backToTop.css('display','none');
}
```

[image: Для наглядности]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@media screen and(max-width: 992px) { .back-to-top { display: none !important; } }
```